# How to put HTML header into a PHP variable

Tags: php, variables

I would like to get my whole site's header into a variable.
So, for example, I would like to put these three lines into a single variable:

```
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

And I'm writing a function for it:

```
function set_header(){
         //This is where i would like to set the variable for the 3 lines I mentioned earlier
}
```

Comment: You can also put the `script` tags in a `header.php` file and then `include 'header.php'`. Just saying; treating plain HTML as plain HTML makes sense.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
function set_header(){
echo '<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.2/jquery.min.js"></script>';
}

set_header();
```

OR

```
function set_header(){
return '<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.2/jquery.min.js"></script>';
}

echo set_header();
```

Comment: It's not cool to echo inside a function. Second variant is better.

Comment: It's general best practice. Functions are to be used to return something. Not to echo-ing it. Using echo preculdes using the function to programmatically build some HTML for output later on, or for further processing.

Comment: For example when you echo the text out of your function just like this: `function yourStatus(){
   echo ' Done';
}

echo 'Status ='. yourStatus();`

Answer (score 2):

```
    function set_header(){
    $header = '<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
                <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
                <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.2/jquery.min.js"></script>';
    return $header;
}
```

echo set_header();